# Где можно найти код такого canvas?

Tags: php, javascript, html, canvas

[image: Canvas]

Где можно найти код такого canvas ?

Comment: ПКМ по странице, на которой вы сделали этот скриншот → «Исходный код страницы»

Comment: уже пробовал (( .

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что явно не по теме сайта

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете использовать библиотеку [particles js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/)

Comment: Спасибо! Это то что мне было нужно))

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле это никакого отнешения к PHP не имеет. Этот код находится на клиентское стороне, следовательно можно скачать HTML, CSS и JS.

Используя  командную строку в Линкусе

```
wget -r www.site.com
```